# About the charts in react-native

Tags: react-native, chart.js, pie-chart

I am working on a project where i am using the charts of react-native in it. 
The "Doughnut chart" which i am using is by default taking 100% as the completion of circle .
I have tried  " Progress Circle" in which the progress for completion of the particular circle is '1'.
 Is there any alternative to change this progress value of these charts  to set a custom value which i want ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa6QG.png)

Below i have given the progress circle sampleimages which takes only 1 as progress i,e. to complete a circle
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riJDU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can render shapes in React Native using React-Native ART

```
Import { Art } from 'react-native';
const { Shape, Group Surface } = ART;
```

You can create shapes using 'd3-shape' npm package https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md .

D3-shape will give you the 'path'. for example:

```
var arc = d3.arc()
.innerRadius(0)
.outerRadius(100)
.startAngle(0)
.endAngle(Math.PI / 2);
```

When you execute this function it will return a long string of letters and numbers which can be used to draw your shape.

Simply, put it into React-Native ART's shape like so:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Surface>
           <Group>
              <Shape d={arc()} /.
           </Group>
        </Surface>
     )
   }
```

Also this is a good article: https://hswolff.com/blog/react-native-art-and-d3/